# Not waking up after screensaver 22.04

Tags: suspend, screensaver

When my computer goes screen blank (even if I set it to 1 minute) screen not turning on when I doing something. Same on X11 and Wayland. And if I suspend from menu screen goes blank, but computer is working and not turning on. Suspending from terminal with

> systemctl suspend

works fine. My computer specs:
[spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhJeY.png)

I found out what causing the problem - Gnome Extension GSConnect. When I turn it off everything works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what happens if you go to Power Settings and instead just set `Screen Blank`? For me, this setting means that pressing any key or moving the mouse wakes the screen up. Go back to basics, turn off Automatic Suspend plus any other associated settings and set options one by one to find which one is at fault. Then report a bug.

Comment: It's all about screen blank. I'm not English user. I will edit my question.