# My ubuntu 22.04 sometimes crashes the screen

Tags: display, screen

I have a few weeks old installation of ubuntu on my PC. The problem is, that sometimes it randomally crashes the screen. Some of the times, the screen goes full epilepsy mode and everything flickers and image gets distorted, and sometimes it just freezes and I can't do anything about it besides just unpluging the computer. If I had some music playing in the background, it still normally plays while the display dies in agony.
It happens almost every day and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: See also [Not waking up after screensaver 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403960/156688)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen artifacts problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920316/screen-artifacts-problem)